# Where can I find more information about the 19th-century magazine The Satchel?

Tags: the-satchel, magazines

In the course of [answering](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/14120/17) a question about an Edgar Allan Poe quote on puns, I came across a 19th-century magazine called [*The Satchel: a Repository of Wit, Whimsies, and What-Not*](https://books.google.com.cy/books?id=RV8TAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), published in London, apparently weekly at a price of 1d. Reading the linked volume (Volume 9, Issues 1-9, Saturday 5 March - 30 April 1831), I couldn't find any actual names of contributors. Articles are signed with initials such as "J.S." or "T.H.B." I also couldn't find any more information about *The Satchel* online, although my search-fu may be bad here since "satchel" is a common noun as well.

**Where can I find more information about *The Satchel*?** I'm particularly interested in a list of authors/contributors, if possible - some information more than just their initials.

Comment: I think you may need a resource like [The Routledge handbook to nineteenth-century British periodicals and newspapers](http://solo.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/permalink/f/n28kah/oxfaleph021904745).

Comment: Some more background information about the magazine: http://john-adcock.blogspot.com/2011/09/satchel.html http://john-adcock.blogspot.com/2014/04/the-purkess-family-of-dean-street.html (from a blog, so take with the appropriate grain of salt)

Comment: Even at the end, in the message where the publication's discontinuation was announced, they still [only used initials](https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=RV8TAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA70&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U24d4LbLEN3moPywPIJGm3PHFlajA&ci=567%2C1223%2C402%2C310&edge=0).